# Finding all exact covers of size k

Tags: c++, r, algorithm, performance, combinatorics

I am looking for some ideas on how to tackle the following problem. My primary language is R.

## Description

I have a set ***S*** and a collection of valid subsets ***U***. I am looking to find all exact covers of ***S*** from ***U*** that use exactly ***k*** subsets.

For example

- set ***S*** = {1,2,3,4}
- valid subsets ***U*** = {{1,2,3,4},{1,2},{3,4},{1,4},{2,3},{1},{4}}
- when ***k*** = 1 there is 1 solution {1,2,3,4}
- when ***k*** = 2 there are 2 solutions {{{1,2}{3,4}},{{1,4}{2,3}}}
- when ***k*** = 3 there is 1 solution
- when ***k*** >= 4 there are no solutions

## Question

In my real life example the set ***S*** has 500 elements and ***U*** has 500,000 subsets. Each subset has between 1 to 8 elements. Using a linear program I found that the minimal exact cover had size 70. I am looking to find all covers that are of size 70. In theory I could loop the linear program adding constraints for existing solutions in order to find new ones. I suspect this will be slow.

I have also attempted a modified dancing links method in R with a stopping point if the depth is greater than ***k***. This works with smaller examples, but seems to get stuck with deeper searches. I could add some improvements by switching to C++ or using more advanced data structures such as ZDD.

Any suggestions of alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

## Attempt with Linear Optimization

Code below is how I found a minimal cover using linear programming

```
library(Rsymphony)

mat #sparse matrix of 1s with dimensions 500 x 500,000
dir <- rep("==",500)
rhs <- rep(1,500)
types <- rep("B",500000)
score <- rep(-1,500000)
max <- T

soln <- Rsymphony_solve_LP(score,mat,dir,rhs,max = max,types = types)
```

Comment: If you share the code you have so far, you more likely to get support here

Comment: Have added in some code to show how I get one minimal cover. It took 15 minutes to find 1. I would like to find all others of that size. I know there are multiple and I suspect based on the nature of the data it is much less than 500k.

Answer (score 3):

You have mentioned in your question that you are open to suggestions related to a Dancing Links implementation and switching to C++ as an alternative so I will make my suggestions related this alternative.

You mention you have already implemented Knuth's Algorithm X via Dancing Links. So without the code I will trust you have implemented it correctly and just mention some crucial optimizations that can speed things up.

1. Make sure that your selection heuristic chooses an item to cover that is the least accessible across all of its available options. In the below image, I select the first encountered, least accessible item to attempt cover with **k** = 2 in order to find one possible solution of the two total. This can speed things up. The item chosen and option used to cover it are both marked with the red asterisk.

[image: select options B and C to cover items 2 and 3]

2. While selecting an item to cover, also make sure to check all remaining items for any that have become inaccessible due to past options selected. If an item has zero appearances across options, you should stop recursing down that branch. This will prune your recursive search and stop you from continuing to explore a pointless branch, also speeding things up.
3. Consider Knuth's most recent modification to the actual implementation of Dancing Links and put the links in an array or vector, rather than as quadruple linked nodes in a grid. You get the same functionality in a data structure that is easy to debug, memory safe, and that provides great locality/cache-friendliness. In C++, here is how I might layout your problem and how the dancing links would appear in memory.

```cpp
struct header {
    int title;
    int left;
    int right;
};
struct link {
    int topOrLen;
    int up;
    int down;
};
/* This vector controls recursion and is how you 
 * decide what item to attempt to cover.
 */
std::vector<header> lookupTable = {
    {-1, 4, 1},
    {1, 0, 2},
    {2, 1, 3},
    {3, 2, 4},
    {4, 3, 0},
};
/* The top row tracks the number of appearances of a given item.
 * Row spacers point to the first item in the previous row and 
 * last item in the current row. Links in each row point above
 * and below--left and right is implicit--and always point back
 * up to the column header.
 */
std::vector<link> dancingLinks = {
    // 0          1         2         3         4
    {0,0,0},    {4,23,6}, {3,20,7}, {3,21,8}, {4,25,9},
    // 5          6-1       7-2       8-3       9-4
    {-1,0,9},   {1,1,11}, {2,2,12}, {3,3,14}, {4,4,15},
    // 10         11-1      12-2
    {-2,6,12},  {1,6,17}, {2,7,20},
    // 13                             14-3      15-4
    {-3,11,15},                     {3,8,21}, {4,9,20},
    // 16         17-1                          18-4
    {-4,14,18}, {1,11,23},                    {4,15,25},
    // 19                   20-2      21-3
    {-5,17,21},           {2,12,2}, {4,14,3},
    // 22         23-1
    {-6,20,23}, {1,17,1},
    // 24                                       25-4
    {-7,23,25},                               {4,18,4},
    // 25
    {INT_MIN,25,INT_MIN}
};
```

Note that in the comments of some of Knuth's [DLX Solvers that use arrays](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/programs.html), Knuth mentions that this array approach didn't do much to decrease number of memory accesses or *mems* as he calls them for the algorithm when compared to linked nodes. However, I still think the benefits mentioned are worth it. Still, this is a hard problem that you describe.

Finally, if you want to see how one possible implementation of Algorithm X via Dancing Links worked out in C++, I solved a problem using that technique here: [dancing-links-and-planning-pokemon](https://github.com/agl-alexglopez/dancing-links-and-planning-pokemon). It's a silly made up problem, but it might give you some ideas for a switch over to C++ and the exact cover implementation is faithful to Knuth's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ***dynamic programming*** technique to update the list of subset combos, *iteratively*.

---

## Code

Here is a base R implementation example of function `f` **that *enumerates* all feasible exclusive subsets that partitions the space `S`** (My code is just an example, which might not scale up well for larger `S` and `U`)

```
f <- function(S, U) {
    # helper function, filters all valid subsets of X in lst
    filterSubsets <- function(X, lst) {
        Filter(\(x) all(x %in% X), lst)
    }

    # helper function, sort list in terms of the list items
    sortList <- function(lst, U) {
        lst[order(match(lst, U))]
    }

    # save result
    res <- list()
    # initial subset list `v`
    v <- lapply(U, list)
    repeat {
        # updated subset list if valid entries can be added into `v`
        u <- unlist(
            lapply(
                v,
                \(vv) {
                    Usub <- filterSubsets(
                        setdiff(S, unlist(vv)),
                        setdiff(U, vv)
                    )
                    if (length(Usub) == 0) {
                        list(vv)
                    } else {
                        lapply(
                            Usub,
                            \(x) sortList(c(vv, list(x)), U)
                        )
                    }
                }
            ),
            recursive = FALSE
        )
        # terminate the loop if no valid entries can be added any more
        if (length(u) == 0 || identical(u, v)) {
            return(res)
        }

        for (k in seq_along(u)) {
            p <- unlist(u[[k]])
            if (length(setdiff(S, p)) == 0 && !u[k] %in% res) {
                # store subsets combos to `res`` if they already cover S
                res <- append(res, u[k])
                # remove it from `v`
                u[[k]] <- list()
            }
        }
        # update `v` for next iteration
        v <- Filter(length, u)
    }
}
```

and a portal function `getSubsetListByCardinality` that gives the list of subsets by its cadinality

```
getSubsetListByCardinality <- function(S, U, K) {
    res <- f(S, U)
    lens <- lengths(res)
    subset(res, lens == K)
}
```

---

## Ouput

```
> S <- 1:4

> U <- list(1:4, 1:2, 3:4, c(1, 4), c(2, 3), 1, 4)

> res <- f(S, U)

> res
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 3 4


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 1 4

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 2 3


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[4]][[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[4]][[3]]
[1] 4
```

and we can also see that

```
> getSubsetListByCardinality(S, U, 1)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4



> getSubsetListByCardinality(S, U, 2)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3 4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 4

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 2 3



> getSubsetListByCardinality(S, U, 3)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 4



> getSubsetListByCardinality(S, U, 4)
list()
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that, the [solution by @ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77037528/12158757) was originally designed to produce ***all*** possible exclusive partitions of `S`, and thus the cardinality of the partitions is not limited to a given number. On top of the all enumerations, `subset` was applied in turn to filter the desired ones with the cardinality requirement.

The advantage of that approach is that, it can obtain ***all enumerations by one-shot*** and then subset it as per the request, but the ***drawback*** is also obvious: ***SLOW!!!***

---

To address the inefficiency issue, we should directly cut through from the requirement of cardinality `K`, and then find all the enumerations based on `K`. A possible approach is using ***recursions***.

## Code

Below is a base R implementation example

```
getSubsetListByCardinality2 <- function(S, U, K) {
    # a backup copy of `U` for ordering list
    UU <- U
    sortList <- function(lst, U) {
        lst[order(match(lst, U))]
    }
    # helper function, enumerates all subset combos of cardinality `K`
    helper <- function(S, U, K) {
        if (K == 1 && list(S) %in% U) {
            return(list(list(S)))
        }
        if (K == 1 && !list(S) %in% U) {
            return(NULL)
        }
        res <- list()
        for (k in seq_along(U)) {
            v <- U[[k]]
            s <- setdiff(S, unlist(v))
            if (length(s) > 0) {
                u <- Filter(\(x) all(x %in% s), setdiff(U, v))
                p <- Recall(s, u, K - 1)
                if (length(p) > 0) {
                    lst <- unique(lapply(p, \(x) sortList(c(list(v), x), UU)))
                    res <- c(res, lst[!lst %in% res])
                }
            }
        }
        res
    }
    # run helper
    helper(S, U, K)
}
```

---

## Output

```
> S <- 1:4

> U <- list(1:4, 1:2, 3:4, c(1, 4), c(2, 3), 1, 4)

> getSubsetListByCardinality2(S, U, 1)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4



> getSubsetListByCardinality2(S, U, 2)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3 4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 4

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 2 3



> getSubsetListByCardinality2(S, U, 3)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 2 3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 4



> getSubsetListByCardinality2(S, U, 4)
list()
```